How do you prove the triangle inequality property for a metric on Gaussians?
$$d(P,Q)=\frac{\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\right)^2+2{\left(\sigma_1-\sigma_2\right)}^2}{\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\right)^2+2{\left(\sigma_1+\sigma_2\right)}^2}$$
How do you go about proving that the formula has the triangle inequality property? That is, for any normal distributions
$$P\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$$
$$Q\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$$
$$R\sim N(\mu_3,\sigma_3^2)$$
have$$d(P,R)\leq d(P,Q)+d(Q,R).$$

Please provide a detailed proof of the process, thank you!

Wondering where this proposed metric came from, I see that $$(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2 + 2(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$$ is $4$ times the variance of the average of two Gaussians. But you have $$(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2 + 2(\sigma_1^2 + 2\sigma_1\sigma_2 + \sigma_2^2).$$

$\qquad\uparrow\qquad$To be clear, I meant averaging the two probability distributions, not averaging the two random variables.

@Yuklam : Do you have a response to the answer below?

$\newcommand\si\sigma$This is not true. For instance, suppose that $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=0$ and
$(\si_1,\si_2,\si_3)=(1,2,6).$
Then $d(P, Q) + d(Q, R) - d(P, R)=-263/1764<0$.
